# Adding Alert to EMA Cloud Fill PineScript Code Based on Color Change

Tags: alert, pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am trying to add a code to a script I found to simply add alerts on the ema cloud based on color change.
I tried to add.

This is part of the script:

```
///////////////plot MAs
plot_ma1 = plot(MA1, color= dynamic ?  dynColor: color.green , linewidth=1, title = 
"MA1")
plot_ma2 = plot(MA2, color= dynamic ?  dynColor: color.red , linewidth=1, title = 
"MA2")
plot_ma3 = plot(MA3, color= dynamic ?  dynColor: color.yellow, linewidth=1, title = 
"MA3")
plot_ma4 = plot(MA4, color= dynamic ?  dynColor: color.white, linewidth=1, title = 
"MA4")
// Trend Fill
rsi1 =ta.rsi(close,14)
smmaLen = 50
//input(50, minval=1, title="SMMA Length", group = "Smoothed MA")
smmaSrc = rsi1
smma = 0.0
smma := na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(smmaSrc, smmaLen) : (smma[1] * (smmaLen - 1) + smmaSrc) / 
smmaLen


trendFill = input(title="Show Trend Fill",  defval=true, group = "Smoothed MA Inputs") 
transparencyValue= trendFill ? math.abs(rsi1-smma): na

bColor = if rsi1  > smma 
color.from_gradient(transparencyValue,0, 50, color.new(color.lime, 80), color.lime)
else 
color.from_gradient(transparencyValue,0, 50, color.new(color.red, 80),color.red)
fill(plot_ma1,plot_ma2,bColor,title="RSI Fill")



// End ###
```

Then I tried to add this to create the alert:

```
    // ### Cloud Color Change
longS = input.bool(title="Show Long Cloud Signal",  defval=true, group = "Plot Mas")
shorS = input.bool(title="Show Shor Cloud Signal",  defval=true, group = "Plot Mas")

longSig =  close[3] > open[3] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close 
< open[1]
shortSig =  close[3] < open[3] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close 
> open[1]

plotshape(bullS ? bullSig : na, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, 
location=location.belowbar, size = size.small,  title="Cloud Color Change Up")
plotshape(bearS ? bearSig : na, style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red, 
location=location.abovebar, size = size.small,   title="Cloud Color Change Down")


alertcondition(longSig, title="Cloud Long", message="[CurrencyPair] [TimeFrame], Plot 
Mas")
alertcondition(shorSig, title="Cloud Short", message="[CurrencyPair] [TimeFrame], 
PlotMas")

// End ###
```

This does not work because what I am trying to do is use the color change from the trendfill cloud to set the alert. What should I do in this instance?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get an alert whenever the color in that gradiant gets updated even slightly?

Comment: Yes. The ema cloud fill has color gradients. The color gradients show when there is a change in trend.

Answer (score 0):

Below variable will become true whenever there will be a change in color

```
colorchange = bColor!=bColor[1]
```